# how to communicate in typical router switch router scenario?

Tags: cisco, routing, subnet

I'm learning routing using packet tracer simulation and I think this is a very commun scenario:

let's say pc4 is the server...
[image]

why I can't ping from PC1 to 192.168.2.253 (router1) but I can ping 192.168.2.2 (pc0) aren't they the same subnet? what am I missing or have to do in order to reach pc4? (192.168.100.254) from pc 1 (192.168.1.1)

is there something like "default gateway" for router?

thanks for advice

PS: during the simulation it shows error "The routing table does not have a route to the destination IP address. The router drops the packe (from 192.168.2.253 to 192.168.1.1)"

Comment: Without giving the subnet mask, you can't say they are on the same subnet. In fact, the fact you inserted a router between the two would indicate they are probably not on the same subnet.

Comment: All have subnet mask 255.255.255.0 as mentioned at the image is that what you mean?

Comment: ahh.. Didn't see the mask in the corner there. In that case, you can't put a router between the two as the whole function of the router would be to forward data between different networks. As you have them on the same network, the router would effectively separate the networks leaving the network on the side of PC4 unreachable and unroutable from the rest of the network.

Comment: *sigh* if you're going to edit and change the original picture and give different devices different IP addresses after your original questionw as asked, at least make a correction to the text in your question.

Comment: O_O I never changed the image. the only thing I edited was to add the post script... and that was just after your first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it work..

As the simulator said, when the package coming back from PC4 to router 1, it doesn't know which route to take to reach 192.168.1.1 so the package is discarded.

What I did is adding static routing at both router or use RIP Routing

static routing:

```
router0 192.168.100.0/24 192.168.2.253
router1 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.254
```

or add RIP routing to both routers:

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.2.0
192.168.100.0
```